# Shovavim and idolatry

Tags: avodah-zarah, repentance-teshuvah, shovavim-tat

The initials of parashat Shemot to Mishpatim form the word Shovavim, which connect this period to Teshuva based on the verse of Jeremia 3:14 where the word Shovavim occurs.

I also read this is a period for rectification of sexual sin. Which from Hosea and Ezekiel could also mean idolatry.

Is there any connection between the teshuvah from idolatry to the parshiot of shovavim?

Comment: I seem to recall somewhere (Medrash? Gemara?) that says that the only reason the Jews served idols was to ave an excuse to commit illicit relations (i.e. denying G-D meant they didn't need to follow any rules, and now they are free to do what they want).

Comment: @user4762 In Likutei Mohoran, Rabbi Nachman ztz"l explains the connection between idol worship and znus

Answer (score 1):

The First Temple prophets used a lot of metaphor describing idolatry as the Jewish people being "unfaithful in marriage" to God.

Today, however, shovavim is a time period when many Jews focus on repentance from sexual sin (or better yet, improved education on sexuality in Judaism). We don't experience the same drive towards idolatry that they did in the First Temple era.

So no, I'm not aware of anyone discussing it vis-a-vis idolatry.